# Undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass <NoMethodError>

Tags: ruby, methods, operator-keyword

Ok I do have the following code

```
 def update_state_actions
    states.each do |state|
      @state_turns[state.id] -= 1 if @state_turns[state.id] > 0 && state.auto_removal_timing == 1
    end
  end
```

now in the line of...

```
 @state_turns[state.id] -= 1 if @state_turns[state.id] > 0 && state.auto_removal_timing == 1
```

it says the error

```
in 'block update_state_actions' : Undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass <NoMethodError>
```

what is the cause of the error? **how come `>` is considered as a method but it is a logical operator?**

Comment: what happens when you use parenthesis like `(@state_turns[state.id] > 0) && (state.auto_removal_timing == 1)`

Comment: `@state_turns[state.id]` has `nil` value... so you need to do something else.. as `Nilclass#>` don't exist..so you got error..

Comment: I just updated the stacktrace error
@ArupRakshit so it points to `>` because the `@state_turns[state.id]` is `nil`? hmmm why doesn't it says like `NullPointerException` hmmm can you  explain further? thank you

Comment: Remember, this isn't Java.  `nil` is an object of class `NilClass`.  `nil` does have methods you can call on it, but `>` isn't one of them.  That's why you get `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> how come > is considered as a method but it is a logical operator?

There is no problem with that. In Ruby, when you write an expression like `1 + 2`, internally it is understood as `1.+( 2 )`: Calling method `#+` on the receiver `1` with `2` as a single argument. Another way to understand the same is, that you are sending the message `[ :+, 2 ]` to the object `1`.

> what is the cause of the error?

Now in your case, `@state_turns[ state.id ]` returns `nil` for some reason. So the expression `@state_turns[state.id] > 0` becomes `nil > 0`, which, as I said earlier, is understood as calling `#>` method on `nil`. But you can check that `NilClass`, to which `nil` belongs, has no instance method `#>` defined on it:

```
NilClass.instance_methods.include? :> # => false
nil.respond_to? :> # => false
```

The `NoMethodError` exception is therefore a legitimate error. By raising this error, Ruby protects you: It tells you early that your `@state_turns[ state.id ]` is not what you assume it to be. That way, you can correct your errors earlier, and be a more efficient programmer. Also, Ruby exceptions can be rescued with `begin ... rescue ... end` statement. Ruby exceptions are generally very friendly and useful objects, and you should learn how to define your custom exceptions in your software projects.

To extend this discussion a bit more, let's look at from where your error is coming. When you write an expression like `nil > 10`, which is actually `nil.>( 10 )`, Ruby starts searching for `#>` method in the lookup chain of `nil`. You can see the lookup chain by typing:

```
    nil.singleton_class.ancestors #=> [NilClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The method will be searched in each module of the ancestor chain: First, Ruby will check whether `#>` is defined on `NilClass`, then on `Object`, then `Kernel`, and finally, `BasicObject`. If `#>` is not found in any of them, Ruby will continue by trying `method_missing` methods, again in order on all the modules of the lookup chain. If even `method_missing` does not handle the `:>` message, `NoMethodError` exception will be raised. To demonstrate, let's define `#method_missing` method in `Object` by inserting a custom message, that will appear instead of `NoMethodError`:

```
class Object
  def method_missing( name, *args )
    puts "There is no method '##{name}' defined on #{self.class}, you dummy!"
  end
end

[ 1, 2, 3 ][ 3 ] > 2 
#=> There is no method '#>' defined on NilClass, you dummy!
```

> Why doesn't it says like NullPointerException

There is no such exception in Ruby. Check the Ruby's [**`Exception`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Exception.html) class.

Comment: First para of explanation nails it :)

Answer (score 2):

It must be converted to integer variable to perform the opercio:

- @state_turns [state.id] .to_i > 0
- state_a = state.auto_removal_timing.to_i  + 1