# Nil error in Ruby, what is happening here?

Tags: ruby

Could someone please explain to me what is happening here and why the first block breaks and the second works? In both examples @final_val is equal to `nil`.

Below doesn't work. The error is `NoMethodError: undefined method`>' for nil:NilClass`

```
if @final_val > value
  Do stuff
end
```

Below works but `@final_val && @final_val` is also equal to `nil`.

```
if @final_val && @final_val > value
  Do stuff
end
```

Comment: Please refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751427/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-nomethoderror#answer-19751692

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short circuit.

In the expression

```
@final_val && @final_val > value
```

because of short circuit of the `&&` operator,  `@final_val > value` is only evaluated if `@final_val` isn't `nil` or `false`.

Comment: That's great, I really confused myself, it's quite simple actually! Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 5):

> NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass"

I think this is comprehensive answer to your question.

Second condition consists of two terms: `@final_val` and `@final_val > value`. After checking of first term second term not checked. It is called [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 2):

`>` has higher precedence than `&&`, so `@final_val && @final_val > value` is equivalent to `@final_val && (@final_val > value)`.