# `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, sqlite

I'm trying to load a remote JSON URL to eventually store it in an SQLite3 database.

I am loading the JSON alright (I think) and then looping through it to assign each JSON value to a variable which will then be built into a db.execute statement to store it into the database.

I am getting an error '`block in <main>': undefined method`[]`' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` when I run the code.

The link [Undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass <NoMethodError>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751427/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-nomethoderror) is full of information but I don't understand what's going on to be honest.  I'm wondering if someone can explain to me where I'm going wrong in my understanding.

My code is:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

tournament_url = "http://www.pgatour.com/data/r/033/leaderboard-v2.json"

puts tournament_url

leaderboard = JSON.load(open(tournament_url))

no_of_players = leaderboard['leaderboard']['players'].length

puts "The number of players to be loaded is: #{no_of_players}"

data_array = Array.new

for i in 0..no_of_players
  current_position = leaderboard['leaderboard']['players'][i]['current_position']     
end
```

If I write any code after the end loop it won't execute.

If had also tried to do a check on the value returned by saying:

```
if (leaderboard['leaderboard']['players'][i]['current_position'].nil?)
      current_position = ""
else
      current_position = leaderboard['leaderboard']['players'][i]['current_position']
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Range `0..no_of_players` is inclusive.

You probably want to use exclusive version (note three dots):

```
0...no_of_players
```

or:

```
0..no_of_players-1
```

Comment: Thanks so simple, can't believe I missed that. Cheers. I preusme I'm right then adding the check for nil otherwise I'll get the error if it is?

Answer (score 2):

`.lenth` returns the number of array items - so the array position of the last item would be `no_of_players.length - 1`.  Basically you get the error because on the last iteration of the loop you get nil.

Instead I might suggest using `.each`:

```
leaderboard['leaderboard']['players'].each do |player|
  current_position = player['current_position']
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was going through the loop once too many times.  Shouldn't have missed it. Obviously your solution would always go through the amount of times in the array.